# UIControlEventTouchUpInside not called after separate touch event

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uicontrolevents

I have an interface where you can hold a button down with one hand, and manipulate settings with the other hand via a pan gesture or a pinch gesture.

The problem is that the `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` callback for my button is never called after one of the other gestures. If I only push and release the button, the callback runs ok, but if I push it, then drag with another finger, and then release it, the callback is silent.

Is there anyway for gestures recognizers and control events to be compatible?

Comment: I think you can do with LongPressGesture and handle states of it, use Simple view instead of Button.

Comment: that worked, I'll accept it if you add an answer